# How is memory used and what is the size of const char* const arr[][]? c++

Tags: c++, arrays, memory, lookup, lookup-tables

I am making a lookup table which will use two keys/indices to access a const char*.

Take for example:

```
const char* const arr[2][3]={
   {"a", "bb", "ccc" },
   {"" , ""  , "dddd"}
}
```

My concern is about the memory usage of such a table, where the real one I plan to make will be on the scale of arr[~60][~2000] with a majority of empty elements. From what I understand, this creates a constant pointer to a 2d array of const char*. What does the memory layout look like for this and how much memory is used? Would the memory use simply be the pointers to each element and the contents of each element?

e.g. (including termination characters) 2*3*pointer_size+(2+3+4)+(1+1+5)

Any feedback is much appreciated, thanks.

Side note: I originally planned on using unordered_map for the lookup table, but that requires the creation of a custom hash when using a pair of ints as keys. Regardless of whether my current approach is the right one, I'd like to know the specific implications of what I'm trying to do above.

Comment: The big three compilers are good at literal string sharing. Which means all literal strings that are the same (like the empty string `""`) will all be a single string in memory, and all the pointers will point to that single string.

Comment: So why not check it with `sizeof(arr)`? A detailed answer to "how is memory used" is hard to give - compiler will optimize a lot, you can expect that at least all same strnigs like `""` will share the same memory.

Comment: you can also create `unordered_map<int, unordered_map<int, const char*>>` w/o custom hash function, or `map<pair<int,int>, const char*>>`.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude What are those big 3 compilers? Thanks

Comment: GCC, Clang and MSVC. Unless you have special needs (some special embedded platform, maintaining older systems, or similar) you will probably never come in contact with any other.

Answer (score 0):

> How is memory used

You never know, until the program is compiled. Only inspecting the assembly code may give you any answers. To be sure, I usually compile with and without some part of code and inspect the output of GNU `size` utility and compare to see the difference a snippet of code does on resulting executable.

> what is the size of const char* const arr[][]?

I believe you know the answer - it's `sizeof(const char *) * first_dimension * second_dimension` *bytes*, as in the example you've given.

> What does the memory layout look like for this

First of all, presented code is invalid - there are too many initalizers for `[2][3]` array. After correcting the mistake, ie. removing the unneeded initializer (because I am too lazy to draw another 3 boxes), the memory layout may look like the following:

```
   const char *arr[2][3]
   +-------+------+-------+------+------+------+
   | 0x... |      |       |      |      |      |
   +-------+------+-------+------+------+------+
       |       |      |       |      |      |
       |       |      |       |      |      +----------->---+---+---+---+----+
       |       |      |       |      |                  | d | d | d | d | \0 |
       |       |      |       |      |                  +---+---+---+---+----+
       |       +---+  |       +------+-+
       |           |  |                |
       v---+----+  |  +---->---+---+---v----+
       | a | \0 |  |       | c | c | c | \0 |
       +---+----+  |       +---+---+---+----+
                   |
                   +-->---+---+----+
                       | b | b | \0 |
                       +---+---+----+
```

Each box represents one element, each box right below `const char *arr[2][3]` is represents one `const char *` pointer, whereas everywhere else each box represents one `char` byte. Note that I drew `arr[1][0]` and `arr[1][1]` to the NUL byte of `"ccc"` - compiler may optimize and merge multiple string literals. Compiler may also not do it - as said above, only inspecting the generated assembly will give any idea what is really going on.

Note that if the array is not mutable, prefer to make it `const`. Doing `const char *const arr[2][3]` when compiling for bare-metal controllers, it will allow the compiler to place the whole array in flash, reducing both initialization `bss` and ram usage. String literals *should* get placed in read only section, because they are immutable. In c++, you might also consider adding `constexpr` (or `consteval`) depending on your needs.

However, you never know until you inspect assembly. If you place the definition of `arr` inside a function, the compile may decide to recreate the whole array (also including string literals) on stack when entering the function [godbolt example](https://godbolt.org/z/eTWr57). Different compiler optimization options come into play.

> Would the memory use simply be the pointers to each element and the contents of each element?

Well, generally yes.